# QMap with pointer as key

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, qmap

I am using `QMap` and I have pointers to the object as keys of the map. Using `std::map` I would write a comparator for pointers and declare my map as follow

```
std::map<Key*, Value, ComparatorOfPointers<Key> >
```

How I have to do with QMap? I cannot find in Qt documentation which template parameters are acceptable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does QMap support custom comparator functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463889/does-qmap-support-custom-comparator-functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QMap` (unlike `std::map`) always uses `operator<` to compare the keys. So you will have to wrap the pointer in a class and define a suitable `operator<` for that class.