# Does QMap support custom comparator functions?

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I couldn't find a way to set a custom comparator function for `QMap`, like I can for `std::map` (the `typename _Compare = std::less<_Key>` part of its template arguments).

Does `QMap` have a way to set one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not documented ([and it's a mistake, I think](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-25304)), but in you can specialize the `qMapLessThanKey` template function for your types (cf. [the source](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qmap.h.html#_Z15qMapLessThanKeyRKT_S1_)). That will allow your type to use some other function rather than `operator<`:

```
template<> bool qMapLessThanKey<int>(const int &key1, const int &key2) 
{ 
    return key1 > key2;  // sort by operator> !
}
```

Nonetheless, std::map has the advantage that you can specify a different comparator *per each map*, while here you can't (all maps using your type must see that specialization, or everything will fall apart).

Comment: Random note: this is gone from Qt 6. Don't rely on this.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as i know QMap doesn't have that functionality it requires that it's key type to have operator<, so you are stuck with std::map if you really need that compare functionality.

Answer (score 1):

`QMap`'s key type must provide `operator<()`. `QMap` uses it to keep its items sorted, and assumes that two keys x and y are equal if neither x < y nor y < x is true.

In case, overload `operator<()`.